# Little Picard’s theorem for meromorhic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

So the statement of little Picard’s theorem is following: non-constant meromorphic function attains every value in $\mathbb{C}$ except maybe one, two, or none point(s) in $\mathbb{\bar{C}}$ Can you provide examples of all of this conditions ?

Comment: Little Picard's theorem is for **holomorphic** functions over the entire complex line, not for meromorphic. The other Picard's theorem is for meromorphic functions around a singularity.

Comment: In my course there is a theorem for meromorphic functions

Comment: It's because you are considering the Riemann sphere $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$, and every entire function on the complex line is a meromorphic function over the Riemann sphere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete edit : for holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$, thus meromorphic on $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$

As $|f(z)| \underset{|z| \to \infty}\longrightarrow \infty \iff f$ is a non-constant polynomial, then $e^z$ has two exceptionnal values ($0$ and $\infty$).

Every non-constant polynomial is surjective over the riemann sphere, and has no exceptionnal value.

$e^z + P(z)$ has $\infty$ as its only exceptionnal value if $P$ is a non constant polynomial

Comment: $1$ is not non-constant.

Comment: Yes. I mean, if you want to avoid two points, the theorem says that you are forced to be constant.

Comment: Sory, I have made the mistake in statement. So for your example $e^z$ has two exceptional values - $0$ , $\infty$

Comment: Okay. I'm editing

Comment: So $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ is not meromorphic over whole $\mathbb{C}$ but it is over $\mathbb{C}$ without $0$? Isn’t it?

Comment: I think for one exceptional point $\frac{1}{z}$ is good. Since the zero is the only one exceptional point. And for two exceptionals $\tan(z)$ is fine. The exceptionals are $i$ and $-i$

Comment: I would add that for a holomorphic function $f$, $|f(z)| \to \infty $ as $|z|\to \infty \iff f$ is a polynomial. So $e^z$ has two exceptional values..

Comment: I completly edited the answer with examples

Comment: Is also rational function ok for no exceptional values?

Comment: $1/z$ works and has no exceptionnal value. In fact it's just the identity map seen from the south pole stereographic projection

Comment: There is one exceptional value it’s zero . Because we need to $z$ be equal to $\infty$ for attain $0$

Comment: And if we construct rational function of kind $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials then we can attain every value from $\mathbb{\bar{C}}$ on $\mathbb{C}$